# JQuery toggle stops working

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have this JQuery code for a slide panel and I have a toggle() to toggle the image.  I am having an isuue of the toggle stops working that switches the image.  I can't seem to figure out why, it seems to be random.

Here is the jquery

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".accord_panel").hide(); // Hide all Panels
        $(".accord_header").click(function (e) {
            $(".accord_panel").stop(true, false).slideUp(); // SlideUp and open panels
            $('.accord_header').find('img').attr("src", "http://www.upc.org/images/skin_images/RightArrow.png"); // Change image to RightArrow
            $(e.target).closest('.accord_header').next('.accord_panel').stop(true, false).slideToggle(); // SlideToggle panels
        });
        $(".accord_header").toggle( // Code to toggle arrow images
           function (t) {
               $(t.target).find('img').attr("src", "http://www.upc.org/images/skin_images/DownArrow.png"); // toggle to DownArrow
           }, function (t) {
               $(t.target).find('img').attr("src", "http://www.upc.org/images/skin_images/RightArrow.png"); //toggle to RightArrow
           });

    });
```

and the css and html

```
 .accord_header
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue' , Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
        color: #615E5A;
        font-size: 9pt;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: black;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 300px;
        height: 30px;
        border-top: white;
    }


    .accord_panel
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue' , Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
        color: #615E5A;
        font-size: 9pt;
        display: none;
        background-color: #f3f0ed;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

<body>
<h2 class="accord_header">
    <img src="http://www.upc.org/images/skin_images/RightArrow.png" /><strong>Panel 1</strong>
</h2>
<div class="accord_panel">
    <strong><span>Panel 1 This is Panel 1
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </span>
        <br />
    </strong>
</div>
<h2 style="text-align: -webkit-auto;" class="accord_header">
    <img src="http://www.upc.org/images/skin_images/RightArrow.png" /><strong>Panel 2</strong>
</h2>
<div class="accord_panel">
    <strong><span>This is Panel 2<br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </span>
        <br />
    </strong>
</div>
<h2 style="text-align: -webkit-auto;" class="accord_header">
    <img src="http://www.upc.org/images/skin_images/RightArrow.png" /><strong>Panel 4</strong>
</h2>
<div class="accord_panel">
    <strong><span>This is Panel 4<br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </span>
        <br />
    </strong>
</div>
<h2 style="text-align: -webkit-auto;" class="accord_header">
    <img src="http://www.upc.org/images/skin_images/RightArrow.png" /><strong>Panel 5</strong>
</h2>
<div class="accord_panel">
    <strong><span>This is Panel 5<br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </span>
        <br />
    </strong>
</div>
```

I also put it in jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/kevdog98/WM6x7/

Thanks for the help.

Kevin

Comment: There is also an issue when you rapid fire click on the rows that has something to do with the `slideToggle()` animation (changing it to `toggle` fixes the issue but you lose your animation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your image `toggle` to use `$(this)`

```
$(".accord_header").toggle(
  function(t) {
    $(this).find('img').attr("src", "http://www.upc.org/images/skin_images/DownArrow.png");
  }, function(t) {
    $(this).find('img').attr("src", "http://www.upc.org/images/skin_images/RightArrow.png");
});
```

When you use `this` you are referencing the `.accord_header` clicked.  When you use `t.target` it will be the element you clicked on which actually might be a `<span/>` or another element which causes your query to find the `<img/>` to fail.

**Update**

I believe the root of the problem was with using `click` and `toggle` on the same element.  The internal tracking of the state of the element was getting out of whack with changing the image.

I reworked your function a bit to simply rely on a click function which seems to produce the functionality you need.

```
$(".accord_panel").hide(); // Hide all Panels
$(".accord_header").click(function() {
    var $header = $(".accord_header");
    $header.find("img").attr("src", "http://www.upc.org/images/skin_images/RightArrow.png");
    $header.next(".accord_panel").stop().slideUp();

    var $panel = $(this).next(".accord_panel");

    if ($panel.is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).find("img").attr("src", "http://www.upc.org/images/skin_images/DownArrow.png");
    }
    $panel.stop().slideToggle();
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/WM6x7/3/), if this isn't what you are looking for let me know.

Comment: That did not fix the problem, I even removed all the span tags with no luck

Comment: Well, moving the **toggle **function** back into the **().click function** and changeing it to **.this** fixed the problem.  Thanks for the help.